# Why do scammers use disperse.app before launching their own tokens?

Tags: wallets

They are not dumping, it’s just that more often than not, at the beginning of the transactions (last pages) there’s hundreds of disperse transactions, often for really SMALL amounts.

What’s the purpose, are those their wallets? I can’t see how they could not be, but there is no benefit in sight - they don’t dump from those, as most scams are very short lived and hundreds of sells would plummet the price drastically, nor are those scam wallet-connect type tokens (of course in case of those the purpose of the usage of disperse.app is obvious).

Answer (score 1):

I would speculate that scammers do this to inflate the numbers of holders associated with the token. This is one of the metrics that people use in determining is a token is an absolute scam. For example, Dextools shows the number of transactions and the number of holders.

Answer (score 0):

Savings in gas.

Individual transaction: 50k gas.

Multiple transfer in one: waaaaaaay more efficient.

---

An alternative (very similar) question could be: why scammers sent you their tokens?

The answer could be: that they want it to show in your account and they know you'll notice.

It's like sending a fax to everyone in the phone book.